# How can I read and log RabbitMQ message content?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am sending a message to rabbitMQ, I want to read this message and log it into a file.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

In order to trace all the messages being exchanged on the RabbitMQ server you can use the [firehose tracer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html).

You can activate/deactivate it with the commands:

```
rabbitmqctl trace_on
rabbitmqctl trace_off
```

Once activated, all the messages will be duplicated to the exchange `amq.rabbitmq.trace`.

Just bind a queue to it and consume from there. You can find a working example in our [RabbitMQ Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/rabbitmq-cookbook).

It should also be possible to directly trace the messages to file by using the [rabbitmq_tracing plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/09/rabbitmq-tracing-a-ui-for-the-firehose/), but I have never tried it actually.

Comment: Include the working example in the answer. Linking to an "account required" site for the answer is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to filter traces and configure the columns displayed you can use the rabbitmq_tracing_ui plugin. The repo is [here](https://github.com/Polezky/rabbitmq-tracing-ui)

Here is the plugin's Featues description

Traces are displayed in a table. Each trace field is displayed in the table column. The following features are implemented:

- Load trace files produced by the tracing plugin which is included in every RabbitMQ delivery.
- Filter out traces by multiple conditions. E.g. filter out by date and time, payload content, routed queues and keys, and others.
- Choose what columns to show/hide.
- Adjust columns widths.
- Optionally format JSON payload.
- Choose the displayed date and time format.
- All filter conditions and layout parameters are saved in the browser storage and are restored when the page is reloaded.

[image: a quick demo]